# How did Sia learn to fight in the movie Baaghi?

Tags: plot-explanation, baaghi

I was watching the Hindi movie "**Baaghi**" and one thing that I was not able to understand was how or when Sia (Shradhha Kapoor) learnt to fight in the movie as during some scenes in the movie she was shown hitting muscled body guards.

Comment: He taught her meanwhile, as you can see in one of the songs.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by SamitJoshi, Ronny trained Sia as we can see in the flashback song below:

Even Sia's father told the filmmakers that she know some kind of martial arts etc too.